# Are there different ways of controlling the font-weight locally or on an uploaded web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

We have created a typewriter simulator which controls the font weight depending on how fast you type, it is controlled with some javascript, some jQuery and styled with css. Here's the link.https://www.dynamik.systems/typewriter/

Before we uploaded it to the site we coded everything with the program Brackets and the font is something we created with a much wider weight then the usual ones.

But now, when everything is up and running it doesn't work like it did from when we coded it locally. No code is changed and the font-face is the same. We have tried it in Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

This is how it looks locally loaded:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RcBL.jpg

This is how it looks now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqIem.jpg

This is with another font that shows that the code is working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYhhq.jpg

We only have tried different types of font styles (otf, ttf, wow etc.) because that's the only thing we can come up with.

The jquery and js.

```
  (function($) {

  let i = 0;
  let lastTime = 0;
  const $output = $("#output");
  const $content = $('#content');

$(window).on("keypress", function(event) {
  // Prevent backspace, enter and escape
  if(event.which === 13 || event.which === 8 || event.which === 27) { console.log('No output'); return; }
  // Keypress counter
  $("span2").text(i += 1 );
  // Intervall for scrollbar
  setInterval(updateScroll,5000);
  // Timer for Key llklkLatency
  let currTime = new Date();
  let ms = lastTime ? currTime - lastTime : 0;
  $output.text(ms + "ms");
  lastTime = currTime;
  // Fontweight
  var fontWeight = ms > 900 ? 100 : 900 / ms * 100;
  // Typewriter
  var key = event.key;
  $content.append('<span style="font-weight:' + fontWeight + '">' + key + '</span>');
  //Font-Weight 
  $("span3").text(fontWeight); 
});


})( jQuery );


function updateScroll(){
    var element = document.getElementById("content");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
}

// Timer

  const output = document.querySelector('output'); 

  let timeRead = false;

  let now = 0;
  let interval = null;

function startTimer() {

  let elapsedMil = Date.now() - now;

  let mil = (elapsedMil).toFixed(0) % 100;
  let sec = Math.floor(elapsedMil/1000) % 60;
  let min = Math.floor(elapsedMil/60000) % 60;
  let hou = Math.floor(elapsedMil/3600000) % 24;

  mil = padTime(mil);
  sec = padTime(sec);
  min = padTime(min);
  hou = padTime(hou);


  function padTime(num) {
    if (num < 10) {
      num = "0" + num;
    }
    return num;
  }

  output.textContent = hou + ":" + min + ":" + sec + ":" + mil;
}

 window.onload = function () {
  now = Date.now();
  interval = window.setInterval(startTimer, 10);
   };

var timer = new Timer();
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener('secondsUpdated', function (e) {
    $('#basicUsage').html(timer.getTimeValues().toString());
});


function myFunction() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.getElementById("info").style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById("content").style.color = "black";
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById("info").style.color = "white";
  document.getElementById("content").style.color = "white";
}

function myFunction3() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF3700";
  document.getElementById("info").style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById("content").style.color = "black";
}
```

Beginning of the CSS to call for the font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "dynamik";
  src: url('https://www.dynamik.systems/wp-content/themes/fonts/DynamikGX.eot') format('opentype'),
       url('https://www.dynamik.systems/wp-content/themes/fonts/DynamikGX.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('https://www.dynamik.systems/wp-content/themes/fonts/DynamikGX.woff') format('woff');
}
```

We expect the font-weight to be as the way when we uploaded it locally.

Comment: So what font is set on the page?

Comment: It's a font we've designed ourselves. We call it Dynamik. (The Swedish translation of Dynamics)

Comment: When I remove the font you set in #content and just set a regualr font family it works fine.

Comment: FYI you have some errors in your console when you load the page.

Comment: If you're going to use jQuery, why all the vanilla JS? Why are you not reusing your cahced jQuery objects? I.E. `#info`, why mix `$content` and `document.getElementById( 'info' )`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that as well and another font works properly. (see third image.) But we can't see why our created font is working when we try it locally and not when we have uploaded it to the site.

Comment: Do you actually have a link to the font file? I am seeing some from google, but I am not seeing Dynamik in the network requests.

Comment: @hungerstar because I'm still learning this kind of coding and have different type of sources to my reference. I have understand that I'm mixing but since it still works locally I thought it were no problem.

Comment: @epascarello I have it uploaded at my server.

Comment: So how is the browser supposed to know about it? Is it linked in the CSS?

Comment: @epascarello Yes! I did add the css to the post!

Comment: I solved it by loading every font-weight needed, in the font-face linking!